# how to solve the compiling error C2079 on windows

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

could someone please help to solve this error :

> test.cpp(14) : error C2079: 'x1' uses undefined struct 'x'
>   test.cpp(16) : error C2228: left of '.x_x1' must have class/struct/union type

here is a part of the code:

```
  struct  x  x1;
  ...
  x1.x_x1=y_x1;
```

On unix, the program is compiling and linking without errors.
Thanks for your help ,

Comment: Please provide the source to the smallest program that shows this problem.  The answer lies in the code that you omitted.

Comment: can you write the code snippet in some detail so that we can have a better look

Answer (score 1):

With just a [forward declaration](http://www.google.com/search?q=forward%20declaration%20c), you can only define a pointer or a reference to the `struct`, you can't access the members (`x1.x_x1`) of a `struct`.

Include the full definition of the struct if you want to access members.

E.g. following would work:

```
struct x {
  int x_x1;
};

struct  x  x1;
  ...
x1.x_x1=y_x1;
```

// or

```
#include "struct_x.h"
struct  x  x1;
  ...
x1.x_x1=y_x1;
```

where struct_x.h has:

```
struct x {
  int x_x1;
};
```